# Adding a child element to a container resets any ongoing css property transitions in other child elements

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations, css-transitions

I have a script that creates a `<span>` every 1,000 ms, adding it to a `<p>` element through its `appendChild` function. The `transition` for `opacity` for these spans is set at 3,000 ms, and I have a `setTimeout` that changes the opacity from its initial value of `0.3` to `1.0` after 10 ms, i.e., right after the element is added it begins transitioning.

The issue I'm having is that once a new `<span>` is added to the `<p>` any currently animating element skips its transition til its end, suddenly *arriving* at the final `1.0` value. Why is this happening? Can't I add an element to a container without messing with currently running transitions?

```js
const text = `This is just an example`;
const words = text.replace(/\n/g, ` `).split(` `).filter(i => i);
let i = 0;

function add() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container'),
    span = document.createElement('span'),
    id = `s${i}`;
  span.innerText = words[i % words.length];
  span.setAttribute(`id`, id)
  const addedSpan = container.appendChild(span);

  setTimeout(() => {
    const el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.opacity = '1';
  }, 10);
  container.innerHTML += ` `;
  i++;
}

const t = setInterval(add, 1000);
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#container span {
  transition: all 3s ease;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<p id="container">
</p>
```

Comment: "Adding a child element to a container resets any ongoing css property transitions in other child elements" well, yes, that is how it works. re: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow

Comment: Just a note: If you want to split a string to words, trim the string, then split it with a regex: `.trim().split(/\s+/)`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss oh, I see... but do you have any suggestions on how I could get around this behavior?

Comment: How dyamic does this have to be? Any reason not to have all the spans created at the start - just don't show one until it's needed?

Comment: @AHaworth 100% dynamic I'm afraid --- my example simplifies this using a pre-defined string, but in the actual application this won't be so simple. what I ended up doing was going through all animating spans whenever I needed to add a new span, pausing their animations, and resuming them once the new span was added.